# how to use maven with intellij 13

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-2

I have some trouble with intellij and maven.

I try to add a library and I do not want to type the text. I want to use the maven repository explorer. When I do this from the project settings->libraries->add from maven the library is fetched but its not automatically added to pom.xml which is what I would expect.

If i use the code generator to add a dependency in pom.xml the search artifact only searches through the libraries already existing and doesn't go through the repositories.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a dependency you need to edit the pom.xml. IntelliJ will ask you if you want to update your project with the updated pom (or just do it if you have enable the auto-import under Settings-Maven-Importing).

Adding a dependency as a library will simply update your .iml (IntelliJ's format of your module information).

Comment: While editing the pom.xml I want to be able to browse the maven central repository but this is not possible in the search artifact tab, it just searches in the local repository.